# Java: Accessing private fields directly from another instance of the same class

Tags: java, scope, private, member

I'm writing a `equals(Object obj)` function for a class. I see that it is possible to access the private fields of `obj` from the caller. So instead of using a getter:

```
Odp other = (Odp) obj;
if (! other.getCollection().contains(ftw)) {

}
```

I can just access the field directly:

```
Odp other = (Odp) obj;
if (! other.collection.contains(ftw)) {

}
```

Is this bad practice?

Comment: May not be an exact duplicate but very close: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1540159/using-getters-or-using-direct-field-access-within-a-pojo

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it's not. The reason that private variables and methods are not accessable from other classes is to allow you to change the internals of your class without having to change all the code that uses the class (that and to prevent the user of your class from e.g. setting a variable to a value that it's never supposed to have).

If you use private variables of other objects that doesn't hurt anything, because if you'd restructure your class's internals, you'd have to change the code inside the class anyway.

Comment: Just because it will work 99% of the time doesn't mean it's the right thing to do.  It breaks encapsulation and couples the classes more tightly for no other reason than saving typing five characters.  Please see my answer.

Comment: "couples the classes more tightly together" - which classes? There is only one class concerned here, and you can't "uncouple" a class from itself.

Comment: Not necessarily.  The parameter passed to equals() is not necessarily the exact same class.

Comment: ^ u mean, ClassCastException?  ;)

Comment: I disagree with this answer. It is better to use accessors.

Comment: @NicolasBarbulesco Stating your opinion without any indication as to why that's your opinion does not really contribute anything.

Comment: Accessors may do special operations, like cloning… When you access a field directly, you bypass these. This breaks the goal of accessors.

Comment: @NicolasBarbulesco But if you're accessing fields of your own class, you know whether the getter does special things and whether you want or need those things to be done in this case.

Comment: @Sepp2k — Not necessarily. For example, I work on a class, I am developing a new method, and I use the accessors, without even wanting to know their detailed operations.

Answer (score 9):

I tend to always use getters, because sometimes a getter isn't just "return(foo)".  Sometimes they initialize things if they're null, or have some debug logging in them, or validate the current state in some way.  It's more consistent.

Comment: +1 If for whatever reason "collection" can be renamed to clearer state it's purpose, I would rather change it in one place instead of every where the getter would've been used.

Answer (score 5):

I dont think this is bad practice, but a feature of the language. It not only allows you to test `equals` the way you do, but it is also useful in a Prototype pattern for object creation.

Answer (score 2):

Using private member for entity class may caused proxy class work incorrectly.
Imagine hibernate create class by lazy query. If you check member variable , it return null.
But if you call get() , it will fetch data from database and initialise the field.

Answer (score 1):

That is fine and completely normal. It is a little bit odd to think that `this` can fiddle with the private fields of `other`, but it's okay because there's no way anything bad can happen as far as some third party being able to muck with an `Odp` object's internals. Any method of the `Odp` class can modify any private members of any `Odp` object, even non-`this` ones, but that's fine since any such methods can obviously be trusted!

Answer (score 1):

This is a duplication of

[Why can I access my private variables of the "other" object directly, in my equals(Object o) method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1581478/why-can-i-access-my-private-variables-of-the-other-object-directly-in-my-equa)

Private data is accessible by any instance of that class, even if one instance of class A is accessing the private members of another instance of A. It's important to remember that that access modifiers (private, protected, public) are controlling class access, not instance access