# Why can I access my private variables of the "other" object directly, in my equals(Object o) method

Tags: java

In Java in the equals(Object o) method I can access the private variables of the passed in object without going through its public getters.

```
public boolean equals(Object o){
    ...
    MyObject other = (MyObject)o;
    return getProp() == other.prop; 
}
```

How's that?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Private data is accessible by **any** instance of that class, even if one instance of class A is accessing the private members of another instance of A. It's important to remember that that access modifiers (private, protected, public) are controlling **class** access, not **instance** access.

Comment: Ahhh I see, I'll be sure to look for this in the JLS

Answer (score 1):

The probable answer is that the designer of the visibility model considers that any developer working in a class has to master the implementation of the whole class.

But this is **a bad idea**. This encourages bad practice. A developer accessing a field of `Person`, in the class `Person`, does not have to know the implementation of the whole class. The good practice is to use the accessor, without having to know what operations the accessor does.